# SecurityException but my code is not called. What is happening?

Tags: android, exception, google-play

On the Google Play Console I have a fairly large amount of the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1703)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1653)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.isRinging (ITelephony.java:2678)
  at android.preference.SeekBarVolumizer.startSample (SeekBarVolumizer.java:655)
  at android.preference.SeekBarVolumizer.onProgressChanged (SeekBarVolumizer.java:506)
  at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh (SeekBar.java:93)
  at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress (ProgressBar.java:1432)
  at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress (ProgressBar.java:1491)
  at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgressInternal (ProgressBar.java:1556)
  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setProgressInternal (AbsSeekBar.java:1531)
  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent (AbsSeekBar.java:1424)
  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.startDrag (AbsSeekBar.java:1368)
  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent (AbsSeekBar.java:1308)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:10779)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2864)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2491)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:605)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1895)
  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent (Dialog.java:894)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:567)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:11008)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4684)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4741)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6985)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

What is quite intriguing is that my code is nowhere in the stack trace. Why do I get this error ? It looks like my code has nothing to do with it, is it normal ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Are you using any feature which depends on any permission and forgot to check it at runtime? Maybe in a receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a SeekBarVolumizer (or some other volume control) in your app somewhere?

It looks like somehow your app is changing the ring volume, and [this requires permissions](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#L5622) `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`, `READ_PHONE_STATE`. Do you have these permissions?

Comment: I do have the READ_PHONE_STATE but not the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE. I will check this. My app is lowering the volume when there is an incomming phone call.